# How to calculate elapsed time of a function?

Tags: delphi, function, time, delphi-xe3

I would like to know how to calculate the time consumed for a function in Delphi.

Then I wanted to show the used time and compare it with another function or component so as to know the faster function.

Comment: Possible duplicate, [`Calculating the speed of routines?`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6030586/576719).

Comment: Definitely a duplicate, another candidate: [Delphi - How to make timer in milliseconds or nanoseconds with start/stop functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834534/delphi-how-to-make-timer-in-milliseconds-or-nanoseconds-with-start-stop-functi)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use `TStopwatch` from the `System.Diagnostics` unit to measure elapsed time using the system's high-resolution performance counter.

```
var
  Stopwatch: TStopwatch;
  Elapsed: TTimeSpan;
....
Stopwatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;
DoSomething;
Elapsed := Stopwatch.Elapsed;
```

To read a time value in seconds, say, from a time span, do this:

```
var
  Seconds: Double;
....
Seconds := Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: Yes, he is my hero too ^_^

Comment: @david-heffernan for **Delphi 10 Seattle** you have to

`import System.TimeSpan`
additionally to use

`Elapsed: TTimeSpan`
successfully.

Comment: No you do not. That's not valid Delphi.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan System.TimeSpan is not valid Delphi?

Comment: @fmmatheus I guess I'm referring to `import` as not being delphi.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Is this feature availaible in Delphi 7?

Comment: @user1141649 No, but you can code it up easily enough using the high perf counter API

Answer (score 22):

You can use the [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions:

```
var
  c1, c2, f: Int64;
begin
  QueryPerformanceFrequency(f);
  QueryPerformanceCounter(c1);
  DoSomething;
  QueryPerformanceCounter(c2);

  // Now (c2-c1)/f is the duration in secs of DoSomething
```

Comment: Secs or ms? Because i got a huuuuge number.

Comment: Mh maybe i did something wrong? ..      Ergebnis := c2-c1;
      Label2.Caption := 'Benötigte Zeit: ' + IntToStr(Ergebnis); And i got this ... Look at "Benötigte Zeit" http://db.tt/cEKKB0w5

Comment: @Polymorphin: Probably. Perhaps you forgot the call to `QueryPerformanceFrequency`, or you forgot to divide the tick-count distance by the obtained frequency.

Comment: @Andreas, I would personally suggest [`TStopWatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) for Delphi XE3. [+1]

Comment: @TLama: I'm still on D2009 and know nothing about it... :(

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, `TStopWatch` is available as a class here, [`How to Accurately Measure Elapsed Time Using High-Resolution Performance Counter`](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/delphi-high-performance-timer-tstopwatch.htm).

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of having more possibilities for tackling the question, you could also use `System.Classes.TThread.GetTickCount` to get a current time in milliseconds to start your timer before your method, and then again after your method. The difference between these two is obviously the elapsed time in milliseconds, which you could transform into hours, seconds, etc.

Having said that, David Heffernan's proposal with `TStopwatch` is more elegant (and more precise?).

Answer (score 0):

```
VAR iFrequency, iTimerStart, iTimerEnd: Int64;

procedure TimerStart;
begin
  if NOT QueryPerformanceFrequency(iFrequency)
  then MesajWarning('High resolution timer not availalbe!');
  WinApi.Windows.QueryPerformanceCounter(iTimerStart);
end;


function TimerElapsed: Double; { In miliseconds }
begin
  QueryPerformanceCounter(iTimerEnd);
  Result:= 1000 * ((iTimerEnd - iTimerStart) / ifrequency);
end;


function TimerElapsedS: string;       { In seconds/miliseconds }
begin
 if TimerElapsed < 1000
 then Result:= Real2Str(TimerElapsed, 2)+ ' ms'
 else Result:= Real2Str(TimerElapsed / 1000, 2)+ ' s';
end;
```